# Edit priv-app / SettingsProvider / SettingsProvider.apk

Tags: android, compilation, rom, apktool

I am new by editing Android ROM. I want to change just one configuration in SettingsProvider.apk. I know how to decompile the apk, the xml file that I need to change and how to compile again. For all this work I use apktool. Also, I learned how to generate a keystore and how to sign an apk but after flash the ROM with this apk into system.img, the phone doesn't start, it keeps in the screen the welcome image. I think that it could be a problem with the sign or another thing about the security of the ROM. Please, help me just to know more about these kind of tasks and if it is possible to edit these kind of apks. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are signing the app.
Don't sign it!!! And push it to the correct folder don't install via adb